# Why is my UILabel nil after creating UIView programmatically from XIB? (code attached)

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, xib, nib

**Question**: Why is UILabel nil here (code attached) in init after creating UIView programmatically from XIB?  (refer to code below)  That is the line `label1.text = "TBC - It was updated"` throws an error

**Background**: I want to programmatically create multiple custom views, multiple GCDateView's in this case.  I want to use a `XIB` file to layout the custom view with an associated class to finalise customisations programmatically too, hence here I have a GCDateView.swift and a GCDateView.xib file.

**Aside**: As a 2nd aside question I note the view I create within the GCDateView from the xib file can't be directly allocated to be the main view (e.g. at the end of init I can't say `self = gcDateViewView`). Perhaps I need a separate question for this.

From within parent controller/view:

```
let dv = GCDateView()
```

GCDateView:

```
import UIKit

class GCDateView : UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    func commonInit() {
        // Programmtically use XIB file
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
            let nib = UINib(nibName: "GCDateView", bundle: bundle)
            let gcDateViewView : UIView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
            gcDateViewView.frame = self.bounds
            gcDateViewView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            addSubview(gcDateViewView)
        }
        **label1.text = "TBC - It was updated"  // ** ERROR: label1 was Nil ****
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        NSLog("GCDateView: Init frame")
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        NSLog("GCDateView: Init decoder")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

}
```

Comment: It is connected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IBOutlet` instances are not initialized in `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.
This process is done in separate step.

There is method `awakeFromNib` where it's guaranteed that all `IBOutlet` instances are initialized:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    label1.text = "TBC - It was updated" // Won't crash.
}
```

To solve your second problem (i.e. avoid adding another instance of self type as self subview) I recommend to create class method that will create new instance of `GCDateView`by loading it from xib.
Here is updated code:

```
import UIKit

class GCDateView : UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    class func loadFromXIB() -> GCDateView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "GCDateView", bundle: bundle)
        let gcDateView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! GCDateView
        gcDateView.frame = self.bounds
        gcDateView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        gcDateView.label1.text = "TBC - It was updated"

        return gcDateView
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let dateView = GCDateView.loadFromXIB()
```

Comment: may thanks - @Visput I don't suppose you have any ideas re my "aside" question?   i.e. As a 2nd aside question I note the view I create within the GCDateView from the xib file can't be directly allocated to be the main view (e.g. at the end of init I can't say self = gcDateViewView).

Comment: @Greg, I updated the answer in order to solve your second issue.

Comment: ok - ummm, actually would that work - e.g. if you were overriding other UIView methods directly under GCDateView (at the same level as loadFromXIB) would they be in scope correctly?  (i'll have to try)

Comment: Thought I was the only one to use this method. All though, you would want to pass `nil` as the argument for the parameter `withOwner`.